# Convertir secuencia de codigo de MSSQL a Python

Tags: python-3.x, mssql

Estoy migrando un proyecto personal a tecnologias mas modernas, y entre esas labores estoy cambiando de base de datos MSSQL.
Tengo un procedimiento que ejecuta ciertas acciones, pero hay un statement que no puedo traducir correctamente a Python.

las variables involucradas son de los siguientes tipos.

```
DECLARE @BinaryLoopType int = 1,@BinaryLoopTime int = 2
DECLARE @Premium binary(30)
```

El dato principal, es leido por este query

```
SELECT @Premium = strPremium FROM ACCOUNT_PREMIUM_DATA WHERE strAccountID = @strAccountID
```

Luego, el codigo que me da problemas son estas dos lineas:

```
SET @SorguPremiumType = CAST(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Premium, @BinaryLoopType, 1)) AS varbinary) AS int)
SET @SorguPremiumTime = CAST(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Premium, @BinaryLoopTime, 4)) AS varbinary) AS int)
```

A continuacion hay una serie de updates basadas en unos `if-elseif-else` que sí sé manejar. Pienso que esas lineas son una manera de encodificar un resultado, por ello no te preguntes por qué se hace un `REVERSE` a un solo caracter.

Soy muy bueno en Python, pero en lenguaje SQL soy un principiante.
He explorado con Python  y obtenido lo siguiente:

```
Query con la parte de Substring: b'\x00'
Query con Reverse + substring : b'\x00'
Query con Cast as varbinary + Reverse + Subtring: b'\x00'
Query con Cast as Int + Cast as varbinary + Reverse + Substring (Total query) : 0
```

El screenshot de la salida de mu Jupyter Notebook esta aqui: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1mr7.png

El equivalente en Python que hice para `SET @SorguPremiumType = CAST(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Premium, @BinaryLoopType, 1)) AS varbinary) AS int)` es:

```
SorguPremiumType = int(
    bytes(
    Premium[BinaryLoopType:BinaryLoopType+1][::-1]
    )
)
```

Este codigo va bien hasta la parte de `bytes()`, pero el 'int()' externo lo rompe, tal vez entiendo mal el `cast as varbinary`.

Lo que leo como resultado de `Premium` a traves del query indicado lineas muy arriba es:

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

Otros valores que encuentro directamente en la base de datos son:

```
0x0AF2DF5F620BF2DF5F620CF2DF5F62000000000000000000000000000000
0x0ACEB261620BCEB261620CCEB26162000000000000000000000000000000
0x0A7A966F620B7A966F620C7A966F62000000000000000000000000000000
```

tal vez con ellos sea mas facil entender las operaciones.

**La pregunta es: ¿Cuál es el equivalente en python de esas dos lineas de codigo?**

```
SET @SorguPremiumType = CAST(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Premium, @BinaryLoopType, 1)) AS varbinary) AS int)
SET @SorguPremiumTime = CAST(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Premium, @BinaryLoopTime, 4)) AS varbinary) AS int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para todos los que se encuentren con el mismo problema, encontré la solución.

El equivalente en Python de la sentencia

```
CAST(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Premium, @BinaryLoopType, @x)) AS varbinary) AS int)
```

Es

```
int.from_bytes(Premium[BinaryLoopType-1:BinaryLoopType-1+x][::-1], byteorder='big')
```

Voy por partes:

La variable `Premium` es del tipo `bytes` y se le toma un substring que empieza en `@BinaryLoopType` y tiene longitud `1` y `4` (respectivamente, para cada una de las dos sentencias a traducir, las denotaremos con `x`). Esta accion de substring `SUBSTRING(@Premium, @BinaryLoopType, @x)` es facil de traducir a :

```
susbtring = Premium[BinaryLoopType-1,BinaryLoopType-1+x]
```

Le restamos `1` por un tema de indexacion de MSSQL vs Python.
Luego, la siguiente sentencia es `REVERSE(...)`, la cual es sencilla de realizar haciendo `susbtring[::-1]` .

Por ultimo, el `CAST AS INT` del `CAST AS VARBINARY` se traducen como la funcion `from_bytes` de `int`. Fue algo complicado encontrar esta equivalencia, pero ha dado resultados.

```
int.from_bytes(substring[::-1])
```

Espero que a alguien le pueda servir esta informacion que me tomo tiempo deducir.